# Is it common to have a bunch of newlines when printing to the console to make things look nicer?

Tags: python, conventions

I'm trying to space out what is output to the console just so things look a little better and I find myself using "\n" in several of print statements to achieve this.

Example:

```
username = input("Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

# check credentials … let "success" be true if successful

if success:
    print("\nLogin success.")
else:
    print("\nLogin failed.")
```

or I could do it as:

```
username = input("Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
print()

# check credentials … let "success" be true if successful

if success:
    print("Login success.")
else:
    print("Login failed.")
```

and then later on I would have to "\n" before the next string when I want to space again (OR "\n" after all the strings)

Is this the correct way to go about it? If so, is it more "correct" to do so at the beginning of string or the end of strings? Or should I be using print() or something? Or is there some other preferred way to format the output in such a way?

Comment: `better` is relative (thus voting to close as opinion based). Make it the way it works for you (and your users).

Comment: just wanted to confirm that this is something that people do since its just so awkward to me to have \n's everywhere

Comment: you do not have to use extra `\n` as python's `print()` would add one by default (see default value for `end` argument). Sometimes you got no LF at the end of output (for any reason, then you want to add it to make output readable). Other languages do not do that so you have to add it if needed. Anyway, as I said - do as you like. as long it works for you is fine. if you got user base, care your users too.

Comment: yes I know that print() does that. im talking about when I want to have a space between output lines

Comment: You want empty line between other lines so you output empty line. You want more space, you output more. Not sure why you need to ask.

Comment: i was asking if it is common/if there is a convention (putting it at the beginning/end, etc)

Comment: Hm, but what other ways of outputting empty lines (other than outputting empty lines) do you know so you got doubts which one to choose?

Comment: well yeah that's what I assumed. I just needed confirmation lol

Comment: @Hello I tend to use a mix of `\n` characters and empty `print()` statements when trying to format output. Another option might be to use `end=\n\n` in the print statement itself, which might keep things more concise and a bit "cleaner". This doesn't seem like it would work in your current case, but perhaps in another.

Comment: Make a logger function/class, and let the user decide with a boolean or integer argument. Then use `Logger.log(str, spacing=3)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Why?

It tidies things up. What if a document's paragraphs were stuck together?

```
   HTML, which stands for Hyper-Text Markup Language, is a markup language for
controlling the elements in a Web page. Its syntax is similar to that of XML
and other markup languages.
   The latest version, HTML5, is an addition to the language, adding elements
and removing a few.
   HTML5 simplifies things up. Now, the doctype was only !DOCTYPE html, and a 
URL to a DTD was not required.
```

Looks kinda messy, doesn't it? Here's the same paragraph with some extra new lines:

```
   HTML, which stands for Hyper-Text Markup Language, is a markup language for
controlling the elements in a Web page. Its syntax is similar to that of XML
and other markup languages.

   The latest version, HTML5, is an addition to the language, adding elements
and removing a few.

   HTML5 simplifies things up. Now, the doctype was only !DOCTYPE html, and a 
URL to a DTD was not required.
```

Now let's look at console output:

```
Initializing...
Welcome.
Logging on...
Searching for server...
Failed. Retrying in 60 seconds...
Failed. Retrying in 60 seconds...
Receiving data...
Connected!
WebSocket ready
<OtherUser> user joined
<OtherUser> Hi!
<Me> yes this works
```

Looks messy doesn't it? Here's the same thing with newlines:

```
Initializing...
Welcome.

Logging on...
Searching for server...
Failed. Retrying in 60 seconds...
Failed. Retrying in 60 seconds...
Receiving data...
Connected!
WebSocket ready

<OtherUser> user joined

<OtherUser> Hi!
<Me> yes this works
```

Looks a lot neater.

## How?

Some ways:

- `print()`
- `print("\nyour message")`
- `print("\n" + "your message")` (cleaner)
- This:

```py
def newline():
    import sys
    # sys.stdout.write = print without the newline at the
    # end
    sys.stdout.write("\n\n")
    # or...
    print("\n")
```

There's no preferred way. It all comes down to personal preference.